# Views Global PHP filter not working properly for rewritten field

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a custom content type in Drupal 7 for real estate property listings. There are two fields in that custom content for property value and currency.

So when someone while creating a new property listing enters value in the decimal text field, right next to it there is a select list which displays 3 currencies Pak Rupees, US Dollars and GB Pounds.

When the listing is saved and displayed with other listings in a Views page, a Global PHP field first determines the value of the property and then calculates the present rate of currency according to the preferred currency saved by the customer.

So the Views page shows the preferred currency of the customer, as defined through a Session, according to the site visitor’s preference.

The value/conversion rate of the currency have been entered manually at the moment and everything works fine except for one thing, when I try to rewrite the Value of the currency field with the Global PHP field calculating the currency, it displays fine but new value does not reflect in the Views Filter Criteria.

So when I try to filter the content according to price, the Views Filter of that price value returns the original value in the default currency (I.e GBP/USD or PKR) and not according to the rewritten Price Field through a Replacement Pattern of Global PHP code.

**field_v** is the value field and **field_currency** is the author’s chosen currency type, both already saved in database.

Here is the Global PHP field code used in the Output code part in the Views PHP field:

> _field_data['nid']['entity']->field_currency[und][0]['value']=="US
>   Dollar") { $rateusd =
>   $data->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_v[und][0]['value'] * 140;
>   echo $rateusd; }
>   if($data->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_currency[und][0]['value']=="British
>   Pound") { $rategbp =
>   $data->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_v[und][0]['value'] * 180;
>   echo $rategbp; }
>   if($data->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_currency[und][0]['value']=="Pak
>   Rupee") { $ratepkr =
>   $data->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_v[und][0]['value'] * 1;
>   echo $ratepkr; } ?>

Then the Value of field_v is rewritten through replacement pattern [PHP_1] and on the views display page it displays the results correctly, but the Filter associated with it to search the properties according to the budget of customer reflects the original value of field_v instead of calculated value according to PHP field.

Any help would be appreciated, I don’t know what I’m missing here but it is very frustrating. Thank you in advance.